# How much does it cost to buy a patent to protect your invention if you are a civilian, a public member?

Tags: patent-applications, employer, government-rights, military, user2174870

I mean by public a person, a civilan acting on his or her private time, a user of the web. I am really not aware if I can enter the building being an homeless in San Jose, Ca, USA. I follow the Law at all time; but I am not a member of any group or any companies.

Comment: I pass in front of it every day...

Comment: What building are you referring to in your question?

Comment: It would help if you could take another pass on this question.  I'm not completely sure what you are asking when you say "buy a patent" (I assume you mean "file a patent") although @DonQuiKong's answer is good, high-level advice.  Be aware, the grant of the patent is what you'd ultimately need.  If it's a design patent, this will be simple, inexpensive and quick.  If it's a utility patent, it will take a few years to find out whether you receive a grant, unless you pay for expedited review.  You also want to explore international filing, although that can get very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

A few hundred dollars at first, around 5-8 thousand if you want a patent attorney.

Later the maintenance fees go up, but you can always abandon the patent / application.

Comment: Adding to DonQuiKong, you probably want to look for a solo practitioner as opposed to a firm, for budgetary reasons (less overhead = lower rates.)  In my experience, there are many such attorneys, and they will consult with you at no charge.  Also, flat rates are often offered and probably a good idea.